# iOS/Android Subscription Offer Code Dynamic Link?

Tags: react-native, google-play, app-store, firebase-dynamic-links

I was trying to find out about if anyone has had any success implementing App Store and Google Play subscription offer codes with a dynamic link.

Some background, we have an online store and a react native mobile app and use Firebase as our backend. We are trying to figure out a way to send everyone who makes a purchase an app subscription offer code but are running into a few issues. The way that we currently have it configured is that when a store user makes a purchase they receive an email with two links in it, one to the AppStore and one to the Play Store. This is inefficient and results in at least 50% of our offer codes being wasted.

One issue we are facing is that we are running out of Play Store offer codes because they are capped at 10k codes per subscription. We are not running into this issue on the App Store because they are capped at 150k. The second issue, which if fixed might help resolve the first issue, is that we are sending each user 2 links. We want to be able to send the user 1 link and have it open the respective app store and apply the promo code. This is where I was thinking dynamic links would come in.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how we could implement a solution where we could send the users 1 link that would apply the respective offer code so that we are not wasting as many codes? Ideally we don't have to redirect the users to a website before sending them to the correct store, but that's what we might have to do but are looking to avoid.

Thanks!